# Signing out using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication using social media accounts. After signing up, I am unable to log out.

The following is my Javascript code:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "*******",
    authDomain: "******",
    databaseURL: "******",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "******",
    messagingSenderId: "*******"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        user.getToken().then(function(accessToken) {

            console.debug('user', user);
            document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
            document.getElementById('name').textContent = JSON.stringify( displayName )
            document.getElementById('email').textContent = JSON.stringify(email)
            document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
                displayName: displayName,
                email: email,
                photoURL: photoURL
            });
        });

      } else {
          console.log('not logged in');
        /*document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
        document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in';
        document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = 'null';
        */
      }

    });

    // User is signed out.
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        // Sign-out successful.
         signOutSuccessUrl: 'https://url.html'
        }).catch(function(error) {
        // An error happened.
        });

</script>
```

And in the html I am calling it by:
`<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="signOut()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out">/i> Log out</button>`

But on clicking the button nothing happens.

I even tried putting the signout segment in a function, but that didn't help.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your click event handler calls a `signOut` method, then you have to define it somewhere. like:

```
window.signOut = function signOut(_e) {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    // Sign-out successful.
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // An error happened.
  });
}
```

Comment: I inserted your code and then checked in the console. 'not logged in' is being shown but it is not being redirected to the page I am mentioning in the url. `window.signOut = function signOut(_e) {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    // Sign-out successful.
    signOutURL: 'https://url.html';
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // An error happened.
  });
}`

Comment: if you want a redirect after the successful signout, then you could add `window.location.replace("https://url.html")` to your `signOut.then` callback.

Comment: Thanks! Also if you see my code, I am trying to retrieve the image of the user as well. In all examples that I have seen photoUrl is used. So as a result only the url is displayed. What change should I do to actually be able to see the photo?

Comment: if you have the url of the image then you could simply render / update an image tag. <img id="avatar" />   document.getElementById("avatar").src = photoUrl;

Comment: Thanks! Both of your solutions helped.